# For each file: Walk line by line and grep for string (incorrect output)

Tags: string, bash, text, sed, cat

Please see below for update.

I am trying to force update the codepage of some email files which are in Japanese. The files are flagged as UTF-8 but the Japanese text is not represented correctly. I need to change the encoding in the header from 'UTF-8' to 'shift-jis'.

I have checked this works manually but I want to automate this process. 
Using two sed commands:

```
#sed -i 's/charset="shift-jis"/charset="shift-jis"/g' $VariableForLine
#sed -i 's/?UTF-8?/?shift-jis?/g' $VariableForLine
```

I beleive I can make the changes required. 
Due to the content of the email I need to restrict this to only change the header of the email. The format I am seeing as standard is as follows:

```
From: "=?UTF-8?Q?JapaneseNameEncodedIncorreclty" <ono.koj@jpm.com>
To: "Yoshi Endo"
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?????????????????=view=?UTF-8?Q????????????????
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Wed, 20 Feb 2006 10:30:22 0100
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;boundary="Next_Item:_(A3CB49KFSA19)/1"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--Next_Item:_(A3CB49KFSA19)/1
Content-type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

?UTF-8?(example to skip)

Ÿž=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-Ÿž
       Japanese Content        
Ÿž=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-Ÿž

?UTF-8? (example to skip)

ここには、ログインしてください
----------------------------------------------------------------
Mixed content
***************************************************************************
Mixed content 
***************************************************************************
--Next_Item:_(A3CB4g7FSA19)/1--
```

Running the two above commands in a loop over the files seems to work but I need to ensure that only the header of the file and the charset variable just after are altered due to the content of the rest of the emails.

The pseudo code which I have made is as follows:

```
for each file in directory of type eml
do 
read file line by line
if line contains "charset=" replace with ??
break
else
if line contains ?UTF-8?
replace ?UTF-8? with ?shift-jis'
exit
```

The further issue with the first clause in the if statement is that the "charset=" string may have no encoding applied, it may be UTF-8 or ANSI so I need to search for the  first instance of charset= and then change the string to add or replace the characters within the "" which comes after.

The code which I am currently having issue with is shown below (please excuse my poor grasp of the syntax)

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in ./*
do
   cat $file | while read myline 
    do 
       if $myline |grep "charset="
       then    
           echo $myline
           #echo $myline #this prints all the content
       fi
      done
             #sed -i 's/charset="shift-jis"/charset="shift-jis"/g' $LINE
             #sed -i 's/?UTF-8?/?shift-jis?/g' $LINE
done #end
```

Thanks for all your input so far. Much appreciated.

edit: I have a solution

```
for file in `find ./ | grep .EML`
do 
        sed  -i  's/charset=".*"/charset="shift-jis"/' $file
        sed  -i  's/?UTF-8?/?shift-jis?/' $file

done
```

IT does not take in to account the header but providing there is no other instances of the charset= code in the email then it should be ok.

Comment: Piping `grep` into `echo` doesn't make any sense at all (`echo` doesn't read anything from stdin).  Can you show us some of the input and what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Can you reduce that whole thing to `grep "charset=" *` ?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the syntax. Piping grep to echo was an attempt to display the resulting string with the correct result. I have tried using the grep statement alone to no avail. I will post results of my run through asap. Thanks for helping guys.

Comment: "Escape" is the wrong term for what you want. "Exit" (or "break", which you use correctly) would probably be more correct.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
sed '0,/charset=/s/old/new/' $file
```

This applies the substitution to each line starting at the beginning, up to and including the first line that matches your criteria. After the line, the substitution is no longer applied, with the net effect of only modifying the first line that matches your criteria.

Comment: This has been helpful. I need to use a pattern match essentially as a Boolean match to allow a break from the editing. I thought grep might do the trick, I can use sed to print out all instances of a match but using it to only print out the first instance has proved tricky.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this to be helpful, but you will need to let me know what the requirements are for the header replacement so I can change the commands to match.

```
for file in ./*
do
    if [[ -f $file ]]
    then
        sed -i '/header_old/{s//header_new/;:a;n;/other_old/{s//other_new/;:b;n;bb;};ba}' "$file"
    fi
done
```

This replaces the first occurrence of "header_old" and the first occurrence of "other_old". There is an outer loop (label `:a` and branch command `ba`) that looks for the "header_old" string and an inner loop (label `:b` and branch command `bb`) that runs once the header replacement is made. The inner loop looks for "other_old". The patterns must appear in that order and on separate lines.

The `n` command reads in the next line from the file. `/pattern1/s//pattern2/` searches for a line containing `pattern1` and the empty pair of slashes reuses that pattern and substitutes `pattern2` for it.